# Bi-Directional Sync between Google Music and Banshee

Tags: synchronization, google-play-music, linux

Is there any way to sync Google Music, preferably including playlists, with Banshee on Ubtuntu 11.10?

The Google Music agent appears to download purchased and free music, but it seems to only be a one way sync (and no playlists at all).

I'd just use the otherwise excellent web app (I actually like it better than Banshee for some things) but it doesn't have the same integration with Ubuntu or the media keys on my keyboard.